# Prove that if $x$ is a local strict optima then $x$ is an unique global optima

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm thinking of the proof of the following Theorem:

Let's be $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a non-empty and convex set and let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ a convex function in $S$. If $\bar{x}$ is a local optima of the problem "minimize $f(x)$ with $x\in S$"
, then:

1. $\bar{x}$ is a local optima
2. If $\bar{x}$ is a strict optima or $f$ is strictly convex, then $\bar{x}$ is the unique global optima.

So far I have proved point 1 and point 2 when $f$ is strictly convex but I am having so trouble findig an argument to prove point 2 when $\bar{x}$ is a strict optima but $f$ is just convex.

I guess it is easy and that the argument has to be similar to that used when assuming $f$ strictly convex but I'm just not having "the happy idea" so any help would be appreciated.

**What I've tried so far**

Let $\bar{x}$ be a local strict optima that is not an unique global optima. Then,

- As $\bar{x}$ is a local strict optima there exists $\epsilon>0$ such as, for all $x\in B(x,\epsilon)\cap S,
     f(\bar{x})<f(x)$.
- And as it is not an unique global optima it exists $y\in S$ such that $f(y)<f(\bar{x})$.

$S$ is convex, so $\forall \lambda \in [0,1], z_\lambda=\lambda \bar{x} + (1-\lambda)y\in S$. Moreover, $\forall \lambda \in [0,1)$,

$f(z_\lambda)=f(\lambda\bar{x}+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(\bar{x})+(1-\lambda)f(y)<\lambda f(\bar{x})+(1-\lambda)f(\bar{x})=f(\bar{x})$.

Then, if we take $\lambda$
 close enough to $1$ we'll have $z_\lambda \in B(x,\epsilon)\cap S$ and that $f(z_\lambda)<f(\bar{x})$ which contradicts the fact of $\bar{x}$ being a local strict optima.

Comment: The proof is the same as the proof that each local minimum of a convex function is also a global minimum, one just has to replace some inequalities by strict inequalities.

Comment: @Daw taking into account your tip I have added to the post what I think I should do but I can "feel" still there is something wrong in my argument. Could you check it?

Comment: the argument is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **what I've tried so far** section if we are supposing $\bar{x}$ not an unique global optima we have then that there exists $y\in S$ such that $f(y)=f(\bar{x})$. So we would have:

$S$ is convex, so $\forall \lambda \in [0,1], z_\lambda=\lambda \bar{x} + (1-\lambda)y\in S$. Moreover, $\forall \lambda \in [0,1)$,

$f(z_\lambda)=f(\lambda\bar{x}+(1-\lambda)y)\leq\lambda f(\bar{x})+(1-\lambda)f(y)=f(\bar{x})$.

Then, if we take $\lambda$
 close enough to $1$ we'll have $z_\lambda \in B(x,\epsilon)\cap S$ and that $f(z_\lambda)\leq f(\bar{x})$ which contradicts the fact of $\bar{x}$ being a local strict optima.